# Can't compile C++ file: does not name a type

Tags: c++

I am getting this error `main.cpp:23:5: error: ‘Department’ does not name a type`

```
/* 
 * File:   main.cpp
 * Author: anonymous
 *
 * Created on May 11, 2015, 9:44 PM
 */

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class College{
    public :
    string name; //for name of the college
    int numOfColleges;
    int numDepartments; //number of departments in this college
    Department* dep; //this will point to the department in this college
    College* next; //the next pointer to point to the next college
    College(){
        name =" "; 
        numDepartments=0 ;
        dep = NULL; 
        next=NULL;}
    College (string n, int numD ){name=n ;next=NULL;}
    void Print(){
        cout<<name<<"\n";
    }    
};

class Department
{
public:
string name;
int numOfStudents;
Department* next;
Department(){name[0] ; numOfStudents=0 ; next=NULL ;}
Department( string n , int numS){ name =" "; n ;numOfStudents = numS ; next=NULL;}
void Print(){cout<<name<<" "<<numOfStudents;}
};

void AddCollege(College *head)
  {
      string n;
      int numD;
      cout<<"Enter the name of the College : ";
      cin>>n;
      cout<<"Enter the number of Departments : ";
      cin>>numD;
      College* tmp = new College(n,numD);
      if(!head)
      {
          head=tmp;
          return;
      }

      College * t=head;

      while(t->next) t=t->next;
      t->next=tmp;
      cout<<"college added";
}

void DeleteCollege(College*&head)
{
    string name;
    cout<<"enter name of college:";
    cin>>name;
    if((!head)||(!head->next && head->name!=name))
    {
        cout<<"could not find "<<name<<" in the list\n"; return;
    }
    if(head->next && head->name==name)
    {
        College *tmp=head;
        head=head->next;
        delete tmp;
        tmp=NULL;
        return;
    }

    College* tmp = head;
    College* t;
    while(tmp->next)
    {
        if(tmp->name==name)
        {
            College* tmp = head;
             head = head->next;
             delete tmp;
        tmp->next=NULL;
        }
    if(tmp->next->name == name)
    {
    t = tmp->next;
    tmp->next = tmp->next->next;
    delete t; 
    return;
    }
    tmp=tmp->next;
    }
    cout<<"could not find "<<name<<" in the list\n";
};

/*Print the list of colleges int the college head*/
void printColleges(College *head)
{
    cout<<"ALL Colleges in Database : \n";
    College * temp = head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
    temp->Print();
    temp=temp->next;
    }
}

void AddDepartment(College *head)
{
    if(!head)
    { 
        cout<<"NO COLLEGES ADDED!!";
    return;
    }

    string n,Dname;
    int numS;

    College* tmp = head;
    College*tmp2 = tmp;
    ;
    while(tmp)
    {
        cout<<"->"<<tmp->name;
        tmp=tmp->next;
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"Type a College name to Add a Department inside\n";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"Enter Department name:";
    cin>>Dname;
    cout<<"Enter the number of students :";
    cin>>numS;

    while(n!=tmp->name)
    {
        tmp=tmp->next;
    }

    if(!tmp-> dep)
    {
        College * tmpD = new Department(Dname,numS);
        Department*tmpDD = tmpD;
        head=tmp;
        return;
    }


    /*if(tmp->dep)
    {
        Department *tmp3 = tmp->dep->next;
        t=tmp->dep;
        dep->next=tmp3;
    }*/

};

//void DeleteDepartment(College* head)
//{
//
//
// ;}

void PrintAll(College*head)
{
    College * temp = head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
    temp->Print();
    temp=temp->next;
    }

};


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int choice;
    College*h = NULL;

    while(choice!=11){
        cout<<"\n\nMenu\n";
        cout<<"1: Add a new college in the list  \n";
        cout<<"2: Delete a college from the list \n";
        cout<<"3: Add a department in a college\n";
        cout<<"4: Delete a department from a college.\n";
        cout<<"5: Print all the colleges along with their departments\n ";
        cout<<"6: Delete all the departments of a particular college \n";
        cout<<"7: Delete all the colleges from the list.\n";
        cout<<"8: Print the total number of students in a college.\n";
        cout<<"9: Find and print the college that has the highest number of students. \n";
        cout<<"10: Find and print the department that has the highest number of students.\n";
        cout<<"EXIT\n";
        cin>>choice;
        switch(choice)
        {

        case 1: AddCollege(*&h);
        break;

        case 2: DeleteCollege(*&h);
        break;

        case 3: printColleges(*&h);
        break;
        case 4:
            AddDepartment(*&h);
        break;
        /* case 4:
      DeleteDepartment(*&h);
       break;
      case 5:
       PrintAll(*&h);
     break;
        case 6:
         DeleteDepartment(*&h);
    break;
         case 7:
        DeleteAllColleges(*&h);
         break;

         case 8:
       NumOfStudentsInCollege(*&h);
         break;
        case 9:
        HighestNumOfStudentsInCollege(*&h);
         break;
        case 10:
        HighestNumOfStudentsInDep(*&h);
        break;
        case 11:
        cout<<"bye";
         break;*/

        default:

        cout<<"\nInvalid menu choice";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @mungaihpk, your edit invalidated the answers. Not good form.

Comment: @mungaihpk I rolled back you last change: It invalidated the answer and your new question was only visible in the comment of the edit. Please accept the answer you received as it solved the problem you asked about. If you have a new question, ask a new question - not edit this one. And maybe also learn how to ask *good* questions by reducing your code to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 5):

Declare your Department class before it's called in College. (Move your Department declaration above your College declaration):

```
class Department
{
 public:
 string name;
 int numOfStudents;
 Department* next;
 Department(){name[0] ; numOfStudents=0 ; next=NULL ;}
 Department( string n , int numS){ name =" "; n ;numOfStudents = numS  ; next=NULL;}
 void Print(){cout<<name<<" "<<numOfStudents;}
 };

class College{
public :
string name; //for name of the college
int numOfColleges;
int numDepartments; //number of departments in this college
Department * dep; //this will point to the department in this college
College * next; //the next pointer to point to the next college
College(){
    name =" ";
    numDepartments=0 ;
    dep = NULL;
    next=NULL;}
College (string n, int numD ){name=n ;next=NULL;}
void Print(){
    cout<<name<<"\n";
}
};
```

Comment: Or provide a forward declaration.

Comment: Forward declarations are more code to be maintained and not needed to solve this problem.